# Assign specific CPU's specific parallel processes on larger Google Compute Engine Machine Types

Tags: linux, cpu, google-compute-engine

I've already found this SU question (it is similar but not the same):

[How to limit Google Compute Engine CPU utilization to 100%](https://superuser.com/questions/1052295/how-to-limit-google-compute-engine-cpu-utilization-to-100/1055129)

I don't want the parallel processing to be sandboxed from each other, the different processes will need to interact with each other regularly... Kubernetes, if I understand the concept correctly, is about sandboxing (containerizing) different processes so that they cannot interfere with each other for security concerns, it's suppose to be the more efficient version of sandboxing VM's (aka I don't have to worry about other people and their VM's infecting my VM)...

The only alternative I can think of is initializing several smaller VM's with only a single CPU that then interact with each other via a REST API but that would be inefficient for my particular project given the amount of RAM needed for the neural network is just a little less than the most RAM available from the largest High-memory machine type...  I know the Intel chips are suppose to have optimization features but there are very specific sections that I could explicitly assign for parallel processing... anybody have a link?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-run-command-or-code-in-parallel-in-bash-shell-under-linux-or-unix/

The syntax is:
command &
command arg1 arg2 &
custom_function &

OR
prog1 &
prog2 &
wait
prog3

In above code sample, prog1, and prog2 would be started in the background, and the shell would wait until those are completed before starting the next program named progr3.

To displays status of jobs in the current shell session run jobs command as follows:
$ jobs

Answer (score 0):

http://www.acuriousanimal.com/2017/08/12/understanding-the-nodejs-cluster-module.html

> NodeJS processes runs on a single process, which means it does not
>   take advantage from multi-core systems by default. If you have an 8
>   core CPU and run a NodeJS program via $ node app.js it will run in a
>   single process, wasting the rest of CPUs.
>
> Hopefully for us NodeJS offers the cluster module that contains a set
>   of functions and properties that help us to create programs that uses
>   all the CPUs. Not a surprise the mechanism the cluster module uses to
>   maximize the CPU usage was via forking processes, similar to the old
>   fork() system call Unix systems.